# WP Redirect is not working

Tags: wp-redirect

I am trying to redirect to another URL using this code--

```
 $siteurl= get_site_url();
//echo " This is basic property search.... now redirecting";
//echo "\n\n Redirect URL for property posts=" + $redirecturl;
wp_redirect( "http://" . $siteurl . "?post_type=property&search_keyword=" + $search_keyword
. "&submit=Search" . "&price-min=" . $price_min . "&price-max=" . $price_max
. "&city=" . $address_city . "&state=" . $address_state
. "&zip=" . $address_zip . "&beds=" . $beds . "&baths=" . $baths);
```

But this is where the redirection is happening--

```
http://dimitri.clientdemos.pw/105&submit=Search&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the correct URL not being used for redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `+` sign for the first instance of string concatenation. Using a `.` instead should fix it.

Additionally, WordPress provides some useful functions that might make this code easier:

```
wp_redirect(
    add_query_arg(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'property',
            'search_keyword' => $search_keyword,
            'submit'         => 'Search',
            'price-min'      => $price_min,
            'price-max'      => $price_max,
            'city'           => $address_city,
            'state'          => $address_state,
            'zip'            => $address_zip,
            'beds'           => $beds,
            'baths'          => $baths,
        ),
        site_url()
    )
);
```

[`add_query_arg()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_query_arg/) allows you to build a URL with new query arguments, instead of using messy string concatenation.